# How to update a content management installation by overwriting existing files via ssh and shell?

Tags: shell, rsync, rename, cp

I have installed a cms (modx) on a webserver running CentOS 5 and Apache 2.2. Now there is a new version and I would like to update it. The instructions in the [modx-wiki](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Upgrading+MODx#UpgradingMODx-UploadingtheFiles) suggest to overwrite the existing files.

I've downloaded a .zip-File and extracted it. The existing installation sits in `html/cms/`. The new files sit in `html/modx-2.1.1-pl/`. I access the server through an ssh connection.

How do I move the new files to `html/cms/` while overwriting existing files and preserving files that are not part of the installation files? I already tried the `mv`-command and read that `rsync` or `cp` might be suitable.

When I tried `mv -ivt cms/ modx-2.1.1-pl/*` it didn't work out. Subdirectories of `modx-2.1.1-pl/` haven't been moved.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a backup of the existing files, just in case.

```
tar czf modx-old.tar.gz html/cms
```

Then use `cp` to copy the new files into place. You can't use `mv` here because it would just skip existing directories instead of recursing into them. But `cp` will do a deep copy, overwriting any existing file in the destination.

```
cd html/modx-2.1.1-pl/ && cp -Rpf . ../html/cms/
```

With GNU `cp`, you can add `-l` to create hard links instead of copying.

Finally you can remove the `modx-2.1.1-pl` directory.

Comment: Actually `cp` would work just fine for this. `cp -r html/modx-2.1.1-p1/. html/cms/` (-a instead of -r would probably be even better though).

Comment: @Patrick: Ah, you're right. `mv` isn't suitable, but `cp` is.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Gilles and @Peter. It worked for me with `cp -Rpv html/modx-2.1.1-pl/* html/cms/`. I used the `*` because I needed all the files under `modx-2.1.1-pl` under `cms`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have the order of the arguments wrong. The usage of the `mv` command is `mv source dest`. If you want to move everything under modx-2.1.1-pl to cms, you should do `mv modx-2.1.1-pl/* cms/`. It may actually be better to use `cp` instead of `mv`, in which case the syntax would be `cp -r modx-2.1.10pl/* cms/`.